# Azure Data Factory web activity to retrieve bearer token

Tags: api, azure-data-factory, bearer-token

I want to invoke an api that returns bearer token (GET method). I can fetch Bearer Token successfully using .Net code. But with ADF I get only 'OK' and I see no option to fetch the Bearer Token.

Example:
ApiUrl = "https://myapi.mysite.org/api/ApiToken?user=u111&password=p111"

if status code = 'OK' then deserialize result content to fetch toekn.

### Sample .Net code I used to fetch Bearer Token successfully:

var result = client.PostAsync(ApiUrl).Result;

string strRes = result.StatusCode.ToString();

if (strRes == "OK")

{

var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

varToken = obj.Token;

}

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **POST** method in Azure data factory web activity to get the access token from an API.

Add header as `content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and pass the access credentials in the body part.

You can refer to this [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/561367/adf-rest-api-bearer-token.html) & [link2](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-data-factory-retrieve-token-from-azure-ad-using-oauth-2-0-9a3ed3f55013) for working examples.

Comment: Thanks, 

The api documentation and the team mentioned to use GET method. After following up with the api team with our problem, they provided a link that supported POST method. Got the token now with POST method.